# wait after presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, modal-view

I need to wait (don't execute the code) after the presentModalViewController until the modal view it's dismissed, it's possible or it's a conceptual error ?

```
-(NSDictionary *)authRequired
{
    //This view write the settings when dismissed (plist)
    [self presentModalViewController:loginRegView animated:YES]; 
    //Read from the setting file (plist) and send back (it's a delagate method)
    NSMutableDictionary *ret=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [ret setObject:[app.settings get:@"user"] forKey:@"user"];
    [ret setObject:[app.settings get:@"pass"] forKey:@"pass"];
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your exact question is. Could you restate it?

Comment: after the call to presentModalViewController the code execution continues. 
I would like to execute the line after that call only after dismissing the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll have to do is create a `LoginRegViewControllerDelegate` protocol to which the View Controller that presents the Modal View Controller adheres, and have your `LoginRegViewController` (or whatever its name is) send a message to its `delegate` that it just closed / is going to close. In this delegate method, your delegate View Controller should read the just-set settings and do whatever it wants with them.

Answer (score 0):

To make your child view controller (modal view) more flexible and reusable you can use `NSNotificationCenter`. [Here's the class reference.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Your modal view should post a notification, that it is going to be closed.
Any other controller, that should react on this notification should add an observer to the same notification center.